# Exporting CSV in Django

Tags: python, django, csv, django-cms

I'm currently trying to export a csv file from a django cms plugin. Only problem is that I don't know how I'm supposed to return an HttpResponse from within a render function.

Any and all help is greatly appreciated!

## cms_plugins.py

```
from cms.plugin_base import CMSPluginBase
from cms.plugin_pool import plugin_pool
from data_viewer.models.data_view import DataPlugin
from django.utils.translation import ugettext as _
from django.db.models import Q
from django.core.paginator import Paginator
import base64
from django.http import HttpResponse
import csv

class CMSDataPlugin(CMSPluginBase):
    model = DataPlugin
    name = _("Data Viewer")
    render_template = "data_viewer/default.html"

    def makeQstring(self, qlist, q):
        out = []
        for fd in qlist:
            out.append("Q(%s__icontains='%s')" % (fd, q))

        return ' | '.join(out)

    def render(self, context, instance, placeholder):
        is_csv = context['request'].GET.get('csv', False)

        if is_csv == 'true':
            response = HttpResponse(content_type='text/csv')
            response['Content-Disposition'] = 'attachment; filename="somefilename.csv"'

            writer = csv.writer(response)
            writer.writerow(['First row', 'Foo', 'Bar', 'Baz'])
            writer.writerow(['Second row', 'A', 'B', 'C', '"Testing"', "Here's a quote"])

            context = response !!!!! I need to return this response, but render can only return a context object

        else:    
            gridData = dict()
            qList = False
            G = context['request'].GET
            q = G.get('find', False)
            paNum = G.get('p',1)
            if q == False:
                q = G.get('q', False)
            if q and instance.filter_fields:
                qList = instance.filter_fields.strip().split(',')

            ordBy = ''
            if G.get('o', False):
                ordBy = ".order_by('%s')" % G.get('o')

            if instance and instance.layout:
                self.render_template = "data_viewer/"+instance.layout
                exec("from data_viewer.models.%s import %s as GridData" % (instance.source, instance.name))

                if GridData and instance.init_filter:
                    if instance.init_filter.strip().startswith('Q') and qList:
                        instance.filter += ' & (%s)' % self.makeQstring(qList, q)
                    gridData = eval("GridData.objects.filter(%s)%s" % (instance.init_filter, ordBy))
                elif GridData and qList:
                    gridData = eval("GridData.objects.filter(%s)%s" % (self.makeQstring(qList, q), ordBy))
                elif GridData:
                    gridData = eval("GridData.objects.all()%s" % ordBy)        

                pg = Paginator(gridData, instance.page_count)
            conObj ={
                'data':pg.page(paNum),
                'pagination':pg,
                'search':{
                    'q':q,
                    'p':paNum,
                    'o':G.get('o',False),
                },
                'object':instance,
                'placeholder':placeholder
            }
            print instance.name
            if instance.name == 'PublicContactCards':
                print 'adding contacts'
                import vobject
                conObj['cards'] = []
                for d in conObj['data']:
                    vcard = vobject.readOne(d.carddata)
                    conObj['cards'].append(vcard)

            context.update(conObj)
        return context
            
plugin_pool.register_plugin(CMSDataPlugin)
```

Comment: What is this plugin for? If it's django-cms or something like that, you should say so.

Comment: Yes, it's django cms. I've now added that to the question.

Comment: I have not worked with django_cms but I've done csv exports. If the requirement is to return a context object, my guess is the the csv response needs to be generated somewhere else or in some other hook for the plugin.

Answer (score -3):

WHY REINVENT THE WHEEL WHEN YOU DON'T HAVE TO?

You can use django-import-export package.

https://github.com/bmihelac/django-import-export